# Poll scm does not find latest gerrits

Tags: jenkins, triggers, pipeline, gerrit

I am trying to use git polling to workaround for missed gerrit event, but apparently jenkins git polling changes is not working when combined with gerrit. I use $GERRIT_BRANCH and $GERRIT_REFSPEC for my pipeline job and get the pipeline from totally different repo. Anybody has some tips? Jenkins ver. 2.46.1, latest gerrit trigger plugins. It complains of:
Ignoring refs/heads/master as it doesn't match any of the configured refspecs

what needs to be configured and where? If I manually trigger/gerrit trigger it works.

log snippet:
Started on Jun 21, 2017 4:39:00 PM
Using strategy: Gerrit Trigger 
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 39f3ecc9b2bb9a3c24b58d6a665b401b59ac5a5b (refs/changes/66/1958366/3) 
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials

> git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/project # timeout=10 
>   Found 1 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/project 
>   **Ignoring refs/heads/master as it doesn't match any of the configured refspecs**
>   Done. Took 0.27 sec 
>   No changes

Comment: Is it possible to get the "exact error message"?

Comment: Hi @AnthonyHorne 
Started on Jun 21, 2017 4:39:00 PM 

Using strategy: Gerrit Trigger 

[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 39f3ecc9b2bb9a3c24b58d6a665b401b59ac5a5b (refs/changes/66/1958366/3) 

using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 

 > git ls-remote -h ssh://server:29418/project # timeout=10 

Found 1 remote heads on ssh://server:29418/project 

**Ignoring refs/heads/master as it doesn't match any of the configured refspecs** 

Done. Took 0.27 sec 

No changes

Comment: sorry about the line breaks, new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Noted as a bug and has forced the user to manually kick off builds, see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42290.

One user noted a workaround that worked for them at: https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/423

- List item

  I couldn't find an easy solution so I falled back on a workaround:
- don't fill the field "ref" > the plugin doesn't use "-h" to list the branch so it sees all of them
- checkout the branch to build in the script to run:
- - git clone
- - cd in the repo directory
- - git fetch origin
- - GIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH#*/} (the variable GIT_BRANCH has the format origin/ so we are ditching everything until the slash)
- - git checkout -b $GIT_BRANCH origin/$GIT_BRANCH ()
- - git merge master (step to check that the commit is mergeable, master can be replaced by the correct branch depending on project)

It is far from a perfect solution but its the best I could find to make it work for my current setup.